# algorithm to get topic / focus of sentence out of words in sentence

Tags: algorithm, nlp, text-mining

Are there any well-know or successful algorithms for obtaining the topic and / or focus of a sentence ( question ) out of the words in the sentence question?

If not, how would I got about getting the topic / focus of the question. It seems that the topic / focus of the questions is usually a noun or a noun-phrase.

So the first thing I would do is determine the nouns by Part Of Speech tagging the question. but then how do I know if I should get just the nouns or the noun(s) and a adjective before it, or the noun and the adverb before it, or the noun(s) and verb?

For example:

In ' did the quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog ', get ' quick brown fox ', ' jump ', and ' lazy dog '.

In ' what is the population of japan ', get ' population ' and ' japan '

In ' what color is milk ' get ' color ' and ' milk '

In ' What is the height of Mt. Everest ' get ' Mt. Everst ' and ' Height '.

**While writing these I guess the easiest way is removing stop words.**

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: You know, natural language processing is not done by an algorithm per se. There is a lot of study around this subject. I don't think you will learn it with a question on SO.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Yes, I know. But there are certain ways in NLP that are quite successful of achieving certain thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be thought of as a parsing problem and I personally find the [stanford nlp](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) tool  very effective .

[Here](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) is the link to the demo of the stanford parser

For the example , did the quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog
The output you get is

```
did/VBD
the/DT
quick/JJ
brown/JJ
fox/NN
jump/VB
over/RP
the/DT
lazy/JJ
dog/NN
```

From the output you can write an extractor to extract the nouns ( adjectives and adverbs if need be) and thus obtain the topics from the sentence .

Moreover , the parse tree looks like

```
(ROOT
  (SINV (VBD did)
    (NP (DT the) (JJ quick) (JJ brown) (NN fox))
    (VP (VB jump)
      (PRT (RP over))
      (NP (DT the) (JJ lazy) (NN dog)))))
```

If you take a closer look at the parse tree , the output you are expecting are both the NP(noun phrases) - the quick brown fox and the lazy dog .

I hope this helps !

Comment: yes, very much! Could you explain to me the parse tree and how to do the extractor? I know how to PoS tag the words, but how to I implement the parse tree extraction in code?

Answer (score 4):

I think first of all that the problem is language-dependent.

Secondly I think that if you have a set of words, you could run a check on their popularity/frequency in the language; f.e. the word "the" occurs much more often that the word "euphoric" => euphoric has more chance of being a proper keyword.

Here the importance of spelling is however crucial. How to deal with this? One idea is to use distance-algorithms such as Levenshtein to words that do not occur often (or do a google-search with the word and check if you get results or a "did-you-mean"-notification)

Some languages are though more structured that other. In english to find nouns, you can run first a check with "a/an word" and then words that end in "s" to find possible candidates for nouns. Then make a comparison with a dictionary.

With adjectives you can perhaps assume that a possible adjective will be located right before the noun. Then just compare the possible adjective with the dictionary.

Then you could of course keep a black-list of words that are never allowed as keywords.

The best solution would perhaps be to have a self-learning neural system but I'm not so familiar with those to give any suggestions

Comment: thank you, this clears things up for me. Now to learn how to make a self-learning neural system.

Comment: no problem. hope that it was of any help! the identification of nouns and adjectives needs still to be elaborated though :)